# Import error with nlp polyglot package in python

Tags: python, polyglot

I am trying to run the base examples of the polyglot

packagehttp://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html

The installation seemed to haved worked, yet when I try to import the packages into a Jupyter Notebook:

http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html

```
import polyglot
from polyglot.text import Text, Word
```

I obtain the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-239bcaca06ea> in <module>()
      1 import polyglot
----> 2 from polyglot.text import Text, Word

/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/text.py in <module>()
      7 
      8 from polyglot.base import Sequence, TextFile, TextFiles
----> 9 from polyglot.detect import Detector, Language
     10 from polyglot.decorators import cached_property
     11 from polyglot.downloader import Downloader

/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/detect/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .base import Detector, Language
      2 
      3 __all__ = ['Detector', 'Language']

/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/detect/base.py in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11 from icu import Locale
     12 import pycld2 as cld2
     13 

/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icu/__init__.py in <module>()
     38 
     39 if sys.version_info >= (3,):
---> 40     from .docs import *
     41 else:
     42     from docs import *

/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icu/docs.py in <module>()
     21  # ====================================================================
     22 
---> 23 from _icu import *
     24 from _icu import _install__doc__
     25 

ImportError: /home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_icu.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6icu_5214LEFontInstanceE
```

nb: replaced my actual username with 'username' in the above snippet.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install polyglot
```

Reference:
[https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook)